# Route that redirects based on custom logic

Tags: angular, angular-router

It seems like all the guides for Angular Router talk about redirecting to a specific route. But what happens if you want to redirect to different route based on some internal logic?

For example:

```
routes: [
 {path: 'link-from-email/:confirmationToken', customFunction: () => {
    myService.checkTokenStatus(token).subscribe((status) => {
      if(status === PREMIUM_ACCOUNT) {
        router.navigate('premium-welcome-page');
      } else if(status === BASIC_ACCOUNT) {
        router.navigate('basic-welcome-page');
      } else {
        router.navigate('registration-page');
      }
    });
}]
```

It seems like the standard way to do this in Angular is by having a route redirect to a component that displays different content in its template, based on what `myService` returns. But there are use cases for not wanting to include this in one template. For example, in the example above, there are three different pages we may want to display, and we may not find it efficient to contain all of that logic inside a single component. Or, we may want to direct the user to two different flows, each organized into separate directories, rather than containing both pages in one component.

Of course, we can create a dummy component with an empty template just for handling this logic. But that seems inefficient.

Is there a way to contain that logic inside the routes somehow? Or do we always have to redirect to a component?

Comment: You can handle this logic in a [router guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards). You essentially put the logic in a guard, then you can apply/reuse the guard on any route you want.

Answer (score 3):

What your after is a guard using the `canActivate` pattern

```
routes: [
 {path: 'link-from-email/:confirmationToken', canActivate: [AuthGuard]
}]
```

And then the AuthGuard Component;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        //Your logic here, then call the navigate, your :confirmationToken should be available from the state object
        this.router.navigate(['/url']);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now what happens when you want to have a generic guard to test whether a user is logged in, in addition to this feature which redirects them appropriately, after they've been authenticated?

Comment: You can have multiple guards on a route, that work like an AND condition. `canActivate: [GuardOne, GuardTwo]`. Also a guard on a parent route, will automatically apply to all child routes.

Comment: If `GuardOne` is your login guard, and it fails, `GuardTwo` won't execute.

Comment: Also just to clarify, your `canActivate` should return true if it is 'successful'

Comment: Actually I'm getting `Error: Invalid configuration of route 'link-from-email/:token'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren` Seems like a component or children are required for a route.